# Include Tikz-documents with a latex body in Lyx

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx, knitr, tikzdevice

I also posted this with a little different focus on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372034/rmarkdown-pass-standalone-option-to-tickzdevice-with-knitr) already, but I am still looking for a elegant solution, so I will try again here.

I use *tikzDevice* in R to transform my graphics into Tikz-Files. Unfortunately these files are standalone-latex documents, so they have a `\begin` and `\end{document}` tag around them and because of this I cannot include the `.tikz`-files as child documents in Lyx.

I might have to cut the beginning and end of the file and then it works, but I'd rather not produce the body or have lyx ignore it. Any ideas?

PS: This is what a `.tikz`-file looks like

```
% Created by tikzDevice version 0.10.1
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\nonstopmode

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[active,tightpage,psfixbb]{preview}

\PreviewEnvironment{pgfpicture}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]

  [...this is where the tikzcode is...]

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it's possible to decide if tikzdevice generates standalone files or non-standalone. Use this second option.

Comment: yes it is and i will check again. I currently call tikzdevice from the knitr-package with the option `dev='tickz'` for all my code-chunks. Unfortunately I haven't fount a way to pass the standalone option to tikzdevice from here and I don't want to call the function for every chunk seperately.